# How to build a mirror server for springframework

Tags: spring, maven, server, mirror

Using Springframework Repo central in China is a pain. I am thinking about to build a mirror for springfw repo.

Like there are plenty of mirrors around the around for maven center repo.

And I know the structure for maven center and springfw repo are both *artifactory* from *Jfog*.

So I think it is possible to set up a mirror for springfw, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Sonatype Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) to do this before, it's available in an open source version that you can run yourself.

I'd recommend setting it up in [proxy mode](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/admin.html#proxy-repository) which means that you will fetch all your artifacts from it and it will in turn fetch artifacts from the upstream mirror the first time and then serve them from a local cache in the future.